# Chrome developer tools javascript version

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

When I open the Chrome Developer Tools JavaScript console to get a REPL, the version of JavaScript it uses seems lower than 1.8. `let` statements, new style functions, etc. give me syntax errors. Is there any way to change the JavaScript version used?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The MDN page for each feature you're looking for will tell you whether you can expect them in another engine -- e.g., [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) is "Non-Standard." But, many of these features have been and are being discussed for [ECMAScript 6](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts) and later under the [Harmony](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:harmony) and [Strawman](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:strawman) namespaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome's JS engine conforms most closely to [ECMAScript 5](http://es5.github.com/). The JavaScript version numbering scheme comes from Mozilla, and features such as `let` statements, `yield`, and others are Mozilla-only extensions to JavaScript.

Comment: I see. I didn't know that. Looks like destructuring assignment isn't available either. :(